What were the main components in the Rise of Sunni Islam in the Middle East during the 20th century?
I am struggling to find articles regarding the rise of Sunni Islam in the Middle East during the 20th century. Frankly, it is most likely because that is a very broad subject. That is why I would like to ask:
what were the main components of this Sunni awakening?
I know that one of the prominent movements involved in it was the Muslim Brotherhood in Egypt and also the Wahhabis in Saudi Arabia. Are there any other notable movements or perhaps ideologists which I should look up?

Not sure what is mean by rise - there were already many Sunni Muslims in the beginning of the century... what might be significant is that WW1 and decolonization resulted in creation of many Muslim majority states... some led by religiously-minded leaders, notably Saudi Arabia.

The question in the title makes no sense, as that's been the dominant cultural movement in that area since it arose there in the 9th century. The first question in the body is a little confusing as well, as "Sunni Awakening" usually refers to the Iraqi movement that happened in the wake of the 2nd Gulf War.

Question might be related to claims that Muslim countries have become more conservative after the 1960s or 1970s?

Founded on facts not in evidence.   Citation? Research?

The Salafi Movement is an example of something like that. You can check this website or Wikipedia for further citations.

https://slife.org/salafi-movement/


Link-only answers are considered low-quality and can be rendered meaningless if the link changes or the target is removed. Please edit the key points into your answer.
